# Option is both a functor and a monad?

Tags: scala, monads, functor

Is Scala's `Option` both a monad and a functor?

As I understand it, functor is just a data type that exposes the following API:

**Functor**:

- wrap (or `apply`) which takes a primitive and wraps it inside the functor
- `map` which takes a functor, unwraps it, applies some function and re-wraps it

So `Option` is a functor. Because I can apply an `Option` to a primitive giving me `Option[T]`. I can also `map` on `Option` to obtain what's inside the functor and repackage inside `Option`.

How is monad different? I had thought that a monad also had an `apply` function and a `map` function. From [this article](https://medium.com/beingprofessional/understanding-functor-and-monad-with-a-bag-of-peanuts-8fa702b3f69e) I gather that a monad **also** has `flatMap`? Which is defined as simply `map` but without repackaging the result inside a monad? (Or is it `map` without repacking the result inside a functor?!)

Since `Option` supplies both `map` and `flatMap` does that mean that `Option` is both a functor and a monad?

Comment: Every **Monad** is also a **Functor**. Not only `Option`, but any **Monad**. - Second the `apply` is not from **Functor**, but from **Applicative** _(which also holds thay every **Applicative** is also a **Functor**, and every **Monad** is also an **Aplicative**)_. - Third, yes a Monad is defined for having also a `flatMap` which is better to think as a `map` which is aware of inner contexts, or as a `map` followed with a `flatten`. But, IMHO, the best way to differentiate between them is the types, `map[A, B](fa: F[A])(f: A => B): F[B]` VS `flatMap[A, B](fa: F[A])(f: A => F[B]): F[B]`.

Comment: You may find this [infographic](https://github.com/tpolecat/cats-infographic/blob/master/cats.svg) _(by **tpolecat**)_ useful, to understand the relation ships between the categorical type classes.

Comment: `Option` isn't a functor or monad in itself. A functor is a three tuple (that satisfy the functor laws); some type (`F`), the unit function (`(A) => F[A]`), and the map function (`(F[A], A => B) => F[B]`). A monad is a three tuple (that satisfy the monad laws); some type (`M`), the unit function (`(A) => M[A]`) and the flatMap (or bind) function (`(M[A], A => M[B]) => M[B]`).

Comment: @marstran: Scala is an object-oriented language, so the operations are part of the type. In that sense, you can say that `Option` is a monad. `unit` is the constructor, `map` is, well, `Option.map`, and `flatMap` is `Option.flatMap`.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I would disagree. One of the main differences between **Typeclasses** and **Subtyping** is that your type not longer _is an X_ but rather _has an (unique) X associated with it_. Additionally, not matter how do you decide to implement them in **Scala** _(or in any language)_, that does not change the mathematical definition of the concept. Now, I deliberately decided to omit that in my first comment because, even if I myself consider those differences important, I have found them hard to grasp when first learning those concepts _(both my personal opinion, as well as colleagues)_.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez By "aware of inner contexts" I think what you're saying is that `flatMap` uses a function that maps an "unlifted" or primitive object to the lifted monad, whereas in the functor's `map` function, the functor _itself_ is responsible for lifting the result?

Comment: @franklin not really, let me expand what I mean with context. Most _"monads"_ _(the 
quotation marks are for the discussion that they really aren't monads)_ like `Option`, `Either`, `List`, `IO` are refereed as **Contexts** or **Effects**, that is because they encapsulate _pure_ values which have an additional _side-effect_ associated with them _(this process is called **reification**)_, for example `Option` encapsulates the effect of a non-total computation, or in other words, a value that may or may not exists. Hoping that may clear what a context is, lets review why I meant with _"aware"_.

Comment: Lets take the following example `safeDiv(a: Double, b: Double): Option[Double] = if (b == 0) None else Some(a / b)`. Given that, you may create this `val r = safeDiv(10, 5)`. Now, you do not have a Double, but a possible Double. Which as itself, is not very useful, since now you can not sum it or do any other kind of computation. At first, you may say, oh i only have to retrieve the value using `getOrElse` with a safe default _(like 0)_. But, what if you right now do not know which default you want, but still you need to operate the value, so you need a way to transform without leaving the ctx

Comment: For that _(extremely common)_ problem, there is a simple solution, just call `map[A, B](fa: F[A])(f: A => B): F[B]`, because `map` will take care of the context for you, and simply apply the function to the inner value _(in this particular case, if it exists)_. Thus, you can do `val r2 = r.map(_ + 1)`. Great, but what if you want to divide the result with another number, you may use `map`... but that will leave you with an **Option[Option[Double]]**, meaning a double possibility of missing, which I doubt is what you want. You really want just a value if both divisions suceded or simply a None.

Comment: Enter `flatMap[A, B](fa: F[A])(f: A => F[B]): F[B]`, basically for this _(also extremely common)_ problem, there is also a simple solution. `flatMap` is not only aware of the context of the initial value, but also is aware that the result of the mapping function will return another context, which it needs to _"unwrap"_ to provide the final result. Thus, you now can do `val r3 = r2.flatMap(safeDiv(_, 0))`. I hope that made it clear. -  BTW, just as a curiosity, we say a **Monad** is a **Functor** because `map = flatMap(fa)(a => unit(f(a)))` also `flatMap = flatten(map(fa)(f))` _(flattenMap ;))_

Comment: So `flatMap` says: "I know that my final result will be wrapped in a context but I may receive an input that is also wrapped in a context, so I will unwrap the input perform some function and wrap the output in a context." In other words it propagates the context. Is that right?

Comment: @franklin Yes, I would just change the _"I may receive an input that is also wrapped in a context"_ with **I will _(it is not optional)_ receive an input that is also wrapped in a context** - _"so I will unwrap the input perform some function and wrap the output in a context"_ at the end yes, you will wrap the result in a context, but the result of the function is also wrapped in a context, thus, you need to unwrap it too. But yes, both `map` & `flatMap` propagate the context. IMHO, a good exercise to understand them is implement them from scratch for varios types like `Option`, `List` & `IO`.

Comment: I have found [these videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FZAmPhjV11A&list=PLJGDHERh23x-9bxGrCbyX-tXJG99XczNC) really well _written_ and super clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: Yes.

Longer answer: Every monad is an applicative functor and every applicative functor is a functor. In Object-Oriented terms: Monad <: Applicative <: Functor.