# What is the advantage of Option/Maybe Monad over Functor?

Tags: scala, haskell, monads, functor, option-type

I understand the advantage of IO monad and List Monad over Functor, however, I don't understand the advantage of Option/Maybe Monad over Functor.

Is that simply the integration of types of the language?

or

What is the advantage of Option/Maybe Monad over Functor in specific use?

PS. asking the advantage in specific use is not opinion-based because if there is, it can be pointed out without subjective aspect.

PS.PS. some member here is so eager to push repeatedly

[Option is both a functor and a monad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56368728/option-is-both-a-functor-and-a-monad)

should be the answer, or QA is duplicate, but actually not.

I already know the basics such as

> Every monad is an applicative functor and every applicative functor is a functor

as the accepted answer there, and that is not what I'm not asking here.

Having an excellent answer here that is Not included in the previous QA.

The aspect, detail, or resolution of each question is quite different, so please avoid "bundling" different things in rough  manner here.

Comment: what would you consider an advantage of Monad for IO/List?

Comment: @Koterpillar IO monad is really necessary for Haskell. Functor does not fit to build IO type blocks such as `print` that type is IOmonad-function itself. For List, the functor can't touch the list structure of the output, but Monad can do.

Comment: @AlinGabrielArhip Thanks for the link, well, somewhat very informative, but does not answer directly to this Question. The accepted answer here is actually really excellent.

Comment: @SmoothTraderKen To paraphrase you a little bit: `fmap` isn't enough for `IO` because if you want to combine, say, `print` and `getLine`, then `fmap print getLine` is an `IO (IO ())` when you really just wanted an `IO ()`. `fmap` isn't enough for `[]` because if you want to `take 3` from each of `["security", "return"]`, then `fmap (take 3) ["security", "return"]` is a `[[Char]]` instead of a `[Char]`. Okay, so: `fmap` isn't enough for `Maybe` because if you want to combine, say, `readMaybe` and `Just "12345"`, then you get a `Maybe (Maybe Int)` instead of a `Maybe Int`.

Comment: @DanielWagner Yeah right thanks. Perhaps, you can also copy the comment, and more detail on `Maybe` would be great as an answer here, then it would be pretty much educational to me and other readers. Thanks again.

Comment: Perhaps reading "[monad in pictures](https://adit.io/posts/2013-04-17-functors,_applicatives,_and_monads_in_pictures.html)" can be of some help.

Comment: @chi Well, that one is not a good explanation, I've been thinking. Perhaps good for understanding Functor, but Monad, applicative is horrible.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let's look at the types.

```
fmap       :: Functor      f =>   (a ->   b) -> (f a -> f b)
(<*>)      :: Applicative  f => f (a ->   b) -> (f a -> f b)
flip (>>=) :: Monad        f =>   (a -> f b) -> (f a -> f b)
```

For a functor, we can apply an ordinary function `a -> b` to a value of type `f a` to get a value of type `f b`. The function never gets a say in what happens to the `f` part, only the inside. Thinking of functors as sort of box-like things, the function in `fmap` never sees the box itself, just the inside, and the value gets taken out and put back into the exact same box it started at.

An applicative functor is slightly more powerful. Now, we have a function which is *also* in a box. So the function gets a say in the `f` part, in a limited sense. The function and the input each have `f` parts (which are independent of each other) which get combined into the result.

A monad is even more powerful. Now, the function does not, a priori, have an `f` part. The function takes a value and *produces* a new box. Whereas in the `Applicative` case, our function's box and our value's box were independent, in the `Monad` case, the function's box can *depend* on the input value.

Now, what's all this mean? You've asked me to focus on `Maybe`, so let's talk about `Maybe` in the concrete.

```
fmap       ::       (a ->       b) -> (Maybe a -> Maybe b)
(<*>)      :: Maybe (a ->       b) -> (Maybe a -> Maybe b)
flip (>>=) ::       (a -> Maybe b) -> (Maybe a -> Maybe b)
```

As a reminder, `Maybe` looks like this.

```
data Maybe a = Nothing | Just a
```

A `Maybe a` is a value which may or may not exist. From a functor perspective, we'll generally think of `Nothing` as some form of failure and `Just a` as a successful result of type `a`.

Starting with `fmap`, the `Functor` instance for `Maybe` allows us to apply a function to the inside of the `Maybe`, if one exists. The function gets no say over the success or failure of the operation: A failed `Maybe` (i.e. a `Nothing`) must remain failed, and a successful one must remain successful (obviously, we're glossing over `undefined` and other denotational semantic issues here; I'm assuming that the *only* way a function can fail is with `Nothing`).

Now `(<*>)`, the applicative operator, takes a `Maybe (a -> b)` and a `Maybe a`. Either of those two might have failed. If either of them did, then the result is `Nothing`, and *only* if the two both succeeded do we get a `Just` as our result. This allows us to *curry* operations. Concretely, if I have a function of the form `g :: a -> b -> c` and I have values `ma :: Maybe a` and `mb :: Maybe b`, then we might want to apply `g` to `ma` and `mb`. But when we start to do that, we have a problem.

```
fmap g ma :: Maybe (b -> c)
```

Now we've got a function that may or may not exist. We can't `fmap` that over `mb`, because a nonexistent function (a `Nothing`) can't be an argument to `fmap`. The problem is that we have two *independent* `Maybe` values (`ma` and `mb` in our example) which are fighting, in some sense, for control. The result should only exist if both are `Just`. Otherwise, the result should be `Nothing`. It's sort of a Boolean "and" operation, in that if any of the intermediates fail, then the whole calculation fails. (Note: If you're looking for a Boolean "or", where any individual success can recover from prior failure, then you're looking for [`Alternative`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:Alternative))

So we write

```
(fmap g ma) <*> mb :: Maybe c
```

or, using the more convenient synonym Haskell provides for this purpose,

```
g <$> ma <*> mb :: Maybe c
```

Now, the key word in the above situation is *independent*. `ma` and `mb` have no say over the other's success or failure. This is good in many cases, because code like this can often be parallelized (there are very efficient command line argument parsing libraries that exploit just this property of `Applicative`). But, obviously, it's not always what we *want*.

Enter `Monad`. In the `Maybe` monad, the provided function *produces* a value of type `Maybe b` based on the input `a`. The `Maybe` part of the `a` and of the `b` are no longer independent: the latter can depend directly on the former.

For example, take the classic example of `Maybe`: a square root function. We can't take a square root of a negative number (let's assume we're not working with complex numbers here), so our hypothetical square root looks like

```
sqrt :: Double -> Maybe Double
sqrt x | x < 0 = Nothing
       | otherwise = Just (Prelude.sqrt x)
```

Now, suppose we've got some number `r`. But `r` isn't just a number. It came from earlier in our computation, and our computation might have failed. Maybe it did a square root earlier, or tried to divide by zero, or something else entirely, but it did something that has some chance of producing a `Nothing`. So `r` is `Maybe Double`, and we want to take its square root.

Obviously, if `r` is already `Nothing`, then its square root is `Nothing`; we can't possibly take a square root if we've already failed to compute everything else. On the other hand, if `r` is a negative number, then `sqrt` is going to fail and produce `Nothing` despite the fact that `r` is itself `Just`. So what we really want is

```
case r of
  Nothing -> Nothing
  Just r' -> sqrt r'
```

And this is exactly what the `Monad` instance for `Maybe` does. That code is equivalent to

```
r >>= sqrt
```

The result of this entire computation (and, namely, whether or not it is `Nothing` or `Just`) depends not just on whether or not `r` is `Nothing` but also on `r`'s actual value. Two different `Just` values of `r` can produce success *or* failure depending on what `sqrt` does. We can't do that with just a `Functor`, we can't even do that with `Applicative`. It takes a `Monad`.

Comment: Also, I am so impressed and surprised you wrote this detailed answer in few minutes after the post of my question. Thanks again.